# How to add a huge list of elements in a tcl list?

Tags: tcl

I have used some tcl code in a design tool to get the list of standard cells in a single list.
Tcl has a limitation of processing a large number of elements to read from any list. How do I split these list of standard cells in a single data structure for the tool to read?

Comment: 32kB is hardly anything (outside of embedded processors); can the tool take things piecemeal?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the tool relies on the tcl code, and I verified that the tcl list itself cannot work (file doesn't get saved ), if the list is too big. Im thinking of a single data structure to store this huge stack of data. Currently, I am splitting the list into multiple lists of list_1 list_2,... and then concatenate them in the tool

Comment: Splitting the list and putting them in a bit at a time was my initial idea too. Tcl itself can handle much larger lists than that — a million elements is not crazy large in my book — but the tool may have all sorts of limits in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a big list that you've got to split into small chunks for processing and don't want to just do all the pieces one by one with `foreach`, you can do this:

```
set big_list {lots and lots and lots...}

set index 0
set stride 10
while true {
    set chunk [lrange $big_list $index [expr {$index + $stride - 1}]]
    # Nothing left; got to the end
    if {![llength $chunk]} break
    incr index $stride

    process_chunk $chunk
}
```

Tune the stride size for how much you can feed through. (Theoretically, you can do auto-tuning of the stride length if there's some complex limit involved. Practically, just pick something by hand that works and isn't too inefficient; auto-tuning algorithms are always quite a lot more complicated.)